# Is it possible to mock the global `document` variable before imports?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, ts-jest

I'm trying to execute a test that makes use of a `react-select` component. On import the `react-select` component by default executes `document.createEvent("TouchEvent")`. I need to override this to ensure that the resulting `blurOnInput` value is false (as I do not have access to the prop directly).

I've tried mocking the function but the import is executed before the mock. I've also attempted to add a separate mock at `__mocks__/document.ts` but this also doesn't get evaluated before the `react-select` import. Any ideas? Is this even possible?